# Input LSTM on multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, keras, lstm

I am trying to use LSTM for time series predictions on multivariate data. I have 50000 samples with 15 dimensions. I want to use look back of 10. What will be the shape of input to LSTM layer. Will it be

```
(samples,look back,dimension) = (50000,10,15)
```

or

```
(samples,dimension, look back) = (50000,15,10)
```

I am using Keras.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can read in the [Keras documentation :](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/)

> Input shapes
>
> 3D tensor with shape `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`.

So the 'time' dimension is first. Since your time dimension is 10, your input shape will be `(50000,10,15)`

I hope this helps :-)